# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra “pisparse”?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, vocabulario, significado, historia

Por más que he tratado de localizarlo, no encuentro en ninguno de los diccionarios oficiales y de referencia el verbo **pisparse** [de algo], que se utiliza en el sentido de “darse cuenta [de algo]”, “enterarse [de algo]”, “caer en la cuenta”, “percatarse [de algo]”, aunque en algunas situaciones contiene cierto tono de malicia o picardía.

Una pequeña variación se produce cuando una persona le pide a otra que “se pispe [de algo]”, en cuyo caso su significado bascula hacia “pon atención…”, “fíjate…”. Por ejemplo, esta frase:

—   Píspate del hombre que acaba de entrar.

Sería equivalente a decir:

—   Fíjate en el hombre que acaba de entrar.

Es cierto que en el Diccionario de la Academia aparece la palabra **pispar**, aunque las referencias son ambas americanismos, y no se corresponden con el enunciado de *pisparse*:

> **pispar**.
>
> 1. tr. coloq. Arg. y Ur. Indagar, oír u observar indiscretamente.
> 2. tr. coloq. Chile. Intuir, sospechar algo que no es evidente.

Lo mismo cabe decir del Diccionario de americanismos, que también la contempla, con una acepción muy similar:

> **pispar**. tr. Ch; Ar:NO, pop + cult → espon. Sospechar o intuir algo que no es evidente.

Hay incluso una acepción de pispar como sinónimo de “beber”.

Mi duda, aquí, es el origen de la expresión **pisparse**: de dónde procede realmente y cuál ha sido su trayectoria con el significado del que hablamos aquí (“darse cuenta”; "caer en la cuenta”, “percatarse”) puesto que hasta ahora no ha tenido cabida en los diccionarios al uso.

**Referencias**

- [Conjugación del verbo **pisparse**](https://conjugacao.reverso.net/conjugacao-espanhol-verbo-pisparse.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cuestión:** Origen de pispar-se

---

Al leer "pispar", pensé que debía de ser de origen onomatopéyico, pues me vinieron varias imágenes de pequeño de esa palabra, psssp, oye, mira eso, que se te cae, esto es tuyo...También, cuando vivía en Barcelona, recuerdo a mis tíos utilizarla para indicar que le habían quitado algo, así pues me puse primero por esa parte..

Así, si en Español pispar significa, Indagar, oír y observar algo fisgoneando en catalán el verbo pispar (en el sentido de "pescar" algo) significa robar, hurtar, también de origen onomatopéyico como intuía.

https://ca.wiktionary.org/wiki/pispar

En Español en este caso igualmente tiene un sentido onomatopéyico, aquí tienes una explicación  más concreta, que indica que proviene de la expresión consonántica ¡psp!.

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?pispar

P.D. Si el tema te interesa existe una obra, en el Boletín de la Real Académica Española, antigua pero interesante, de García Diego, sobre "Etimologías Naturales". Saludos

https://apps.rae.es/BRAE_DB_PDF/TOMO_XLV/CLXXVI/GarciadeDiego_421_476.pdf

Comment: La de su origen onomatopéyico es una de las hipótesis para **pispar**, con las acepciones apuntadas por mí y por ti. Mi pregunta es sobre el verbo **pisparse**, que como ya indiqué en la pregunta no tiene el mismo significado.

Comment: En cualquier caso: gracias por el documento, que me parece tan curioso como interesante.

Comment: Sigo pensando que "pisparse" es simplemente el desarrollo en la forma pronominal del verbo, mientras que "pispar" es el verbo transitivo. Además, la 2 acep. "sospechar ó intuir algo que no es evidente" es "pisparse". Si se sospecha ó intuye que algo no es evidente es porque (alguien) se esta dando cuenta de esa evidencia. Intuir "que algo no es evidente" es por tanto, "darse cuenta de (algo) " ó pisparse. Así como verbo transitivo "pispar" significaría lo que aparece en la RAE, mientras "pisparse", como verbo pronominal significaría darse cuenta, percibir, reparar en algo, enterarse de algo...